# How to mock in Symfony functionnal tests?

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpunit, symfony-3.4

I'm creating functionnal tests on a Symfony 3.4 application.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class UserControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * Connect to the website while being logged in
     * Logs in with (admin, password : a)
     */
    public function connection()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $container = static::$kernel->getContainer();
        $session = $container->get('session');
        // Get the user (has to exist in the database)
        $person = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneByUsername('admin');
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($person, null, 'main', $person->getRoles());
        $session->set('_security_main', serialize($token));
        $session->save();
        $client->getCookieJar()->set(new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId()));
        // Return the client
        return $client;
    }

    public function accessEditPage()
    {
        $client = $this->connection();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/user/');
        $this->assertSame(Response::HTTP_OK, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
        $this->assertContains(
                'Liste des utilisateurices',
                $client->getResponse()->getContent()
        );
        // Select the button of the user created for the test
        // Wont work if there are already more than 10 users in the database
        $link = $crawler
            ->filter('tr > td > a:contains("")')
            ->last()
            ->link()
        ;
        $crawler = $client->click($link);
        return array($client,$crawler);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user
     */
    public function testCreate()
    {
        $client = $this->connection();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/user/new');
        $this->assertSame(Response::HTTP_OK, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());

        // Vérifie si la page affiche le bon texte
        $this->assertContains(
                'Enregistrer',
                $client->getResponse()->getContent()
        );

        // Select the form and fill its values
        $form = $crawler->selectButton(' Créer')->form();
        $values = $form->getPhpValues();
        $values['appbundle_user']['username'] = 'Jean';
        $values['appbundle_user']['plainPassword']['first'] = 'motdepasse';
        $values['appbundle_user']['plainPassword']['second'] = 'motdepasse';

        $crawler = $client->request($form->getMethod(), $form->getUri(), $values,$form->getPhpFiles());
        $crawler = $client->followRedirect();
        $this->assertContains(
                'Jean',
                $client->getResponse()->getContent()
        );
    }
}
```

Currently, my Controller tests create databases entries and depends on existing ones and that's a problem.

I want to mock the repositories used in the controller to avoid creating entries when I test my controllers but I haven't found helpful documentation about it. As I can't find documentation, I also wonder if what I want to do is a good practice or not.

Comment: Trying to mix Mocking and WebTestCase seldom ends well.  The whole point of using WebTestCase is to provide a means of end to end testing.  Throwing mocks in there pretty makes your tests useless.  If you really want to use the WebTestCase then initialize your database for each test and then destroy.  But the real problem is that you seem to have business logic inside of your controller actions.  Big no no.  Move the logic to their own classes and then use unit tests.  Controller actions should be thin.  No real need to test them.

Comment: You can test controllers and services alone (if you inject the services and repositories in the constructor) with this https://github.com/mockery/mockery

Comment: @Cerad so I dont do what I want in my tests, I would like some unit tests like on my controllers, not an end to end test of a scenario. I do have a lot of logic in my controller, because at my previous work, we did put a lot of logic in them. How should I move this logic?

Comment: This is one of those open ended questions that is pretty much impossible to answer without specifics.  In your posted code you have a comment "more than 10 users".  How do you count users?  Is it a repository method or do you actually build and execute the query in your controller?  By making it a repository method then you could write a unit test for it.  Repeat the process for any other bits of logic.  It will probably not be easy.  Apps really need to be designed from the ground up to be unit testable.

Comment: Oh sorry, that's because I didn't implement a teardown method that clean my database for now, that's a reminder for me of why the tests don't pass if I messed up my data.
Ok thanks, I think I understand what you mean! So basically, models, repositories and services can be unit tested, with mock for services for example, but controllers only need to be tested in end to end?

Comment: Pretty much.  There is a wide range of opinions on testing a controller actions.  I seldom bother. But I usually do make a few end to end tests just to check for gross errors.  Heartbeat type tests.